# Access Python XML-RPC Service from Ruby Client

Tags: python, ruby, xml-rpc

I have a XMLRPC server running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import subprocess
import os


def testls():
    retcode=subprocess.call(["ls", "/etc"])
    return retcode



server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('192.168.15.20',8888),logRequests=True)

server.register_function(testls)

server.register_introspection_functions()
try:
    server.serve_forever()
finally:
    server.server_close()
```

I need to be able to call it from a ruby client. From what I have found. it seems that it should be this:

```
require xmlrpc/client
server = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://192.168.15.20:8888/")
```

But it returns the following, which suggests that it is not able to reach the service.

```
=> #<XMLRPC::Client:0x2ab0f5caacf8 @parser=nil, @timeout=30, @path="/", @password=nil, @http_header_extra=nil, @use_ssl=false, @host="192.168.15.20", @user=nil, @proxy_port=nil, @auth=nil, @cookie=nil, @create=nil, @port=8888, @http=#<Net::HTTP 192.168.15.20:8888 open=false>, @proxy_host=nil, @http_last_response=nil>
```

I had better success with the following, but I was not able to invoke the method:

```
irb(main):069:0> server = XMLRPC::Client::Proxy.new("http://192.168.15.20","8888")
=> #<XMLRPC::Client::Proxy:0x2ab0f5c4ef48 @args=[], @server="http://192.168.15.20", @meth=:call, @prefix="8888.">
irb(main):070:0> s = server.call('system.listMethods')
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for "http://192.168.15.20":String
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:608:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:608:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):70
        from :0
```

What is the appropriate code to invoke a call from Ruby to a Python XML-RPC Server?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question, but since it doesn't have a selected answer, I thought I'd share my insights:

In ruby, the class `XMLRPC::Client` represents a lower level interface to the server:

```
server = XMLRPC::Client.new( "192.168.15.20", 8888 )
server.call 'system.listMethods'
```

The class `XMLRPC::Client::Proxy` is a higher level interface to (parts of) the server that allows for a more natural server method invocation:

```
system = server.proxy('system')
system.listMethods
```

Similarly, to access the server's 'root' methods (like those registered via `register_function` in Python):

```
main = server.proxy
main.testls
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with xmlrpc in Ruby, but I think you have to pass an XMLRPC::Client Object to XMLRPC::Client::Proxy.
Try stuff like this:

```
client = XMLRPC::Client.new( "http://192.168.15.20", 8888 )
server = XMLRPC::Client::Proxy.new( client, 8888 )
server.call "system.listMethods"
```

Maybe it works this way.